# Hide components in react with dynamic urls change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on to hide the components where a page is rendered out of various components.
Below is the example of the rendered page with various components.

How can hide the components when ever the url changes and what could be the best way to hide components for dynamic urls?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import all the compoent A, B AND C

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
               <Component A/>
               <Component B/>
              <Component C/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have got to the point where I can hide the components using

## 1 . method using an if else statement

```
if(condition)
{
render{}
else{
render{}
}
```

#2 . use tenary operator according to the condition that i want

The common solution that went to do is
window.location.href ---> and check the string with the url string that i want and use the if else condtion.

Could anyone guide a better way to hide the components while rendering with url change and make it more configurable?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use React-Router https://reactrouter.com/. They have an easy to follow tutorial on their website that will tell you how to dynamically show different components based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if else` based on the condition

You can render components based on the specific url destinations

For example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<App />}>
  <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />}>
    <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
      <Route path=":invoice" element={<Invoice />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

For the following website. Focus on the website url
[image]

For quick start follow: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Comment: but if i want to render multiple components, it will lot elements in the route path? @Krishna Acharya

Comment: i didn't understand your question, But using the react components you can nest the routes for example Everthing is under the <App> component so '/ ' will just render the App component. Similary '/sales' renders <Sales> component within the App component. '/sales/invoices' will render <Invoices> and so on

Comment: <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>, i was just asking  rendering all sales, invoices components ,  <Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Nav/><Etc./></>}/>
, thanks so much for that

Comment: can i do this with react-router version 4, the older one ? @Krishna Acharya